# How do I escape double quotes within single quotes in PHP?

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to output a value as a HTML attribute in PHP, but I only want the attribute to exist if the value is set.

```
    <div <?= ($value) ? 'data-value="PHP VARIABLE"' : ''?>>
```

How can I escape the double quotes and insert a PHP variable?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the entire `div` to not be added use:

```
<div <?php echo ($value ? 'data-value="' . $phpvariable . '"' : ''); ?> >
```

That also assumes that `$value` is going to be true or false.

Comment: Hi, I want the div to exist all the time - just want the HTML attribute to be dependent on whether the variable is set or not.

Thanks.

Comment: Modified my answer so you'll always get the div.

Comment: You forgot a single quote before 'data-value' but after adding one - it works.

Thanks for your help!